# Como usar a função toupper() em char em C?

Tags: c, string, if, comparação, char

Estou criando uma variável:

```
char nome[20];
```

Após isto, eu estou pedindo para que o usuário entre com um nome:

```
printf("Digite um nome : ");
scanf("%20s",&nome);
```

E estou fazendo a verificação para ver se o nome está correto:

```
if(strcmp(nome,"Maria") == 0){
    printf("\nCor favorita : Vermelho");
    printf("\nFruta favorita : Morango");
}
```

O problema é que preciso fazer isto, usando a função `toupper()` para caso que o usuário digite o nome minúsculo, ele faça com que fique maiúsculo, portanto funcionando o `if`.

Tentativa do `if` com `toupper`:

```
if(strcmp(toupper(nome,"maria")== 0)){
        printf("\nCor favorita : Vermelho");
        printf("\nFruta favorita : Morango");
    }
```

**Erros :**

> invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
>
> too many arguments to function 'int toupper(int)'
>
> cannot convert 'bool' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int strcmp(const char*, const char*)'

Eu teria que converter a variável com a função `toupper()` antes do `if`? Ou dentro dele ?

Comment: Coloque o código que tentou pra gente ver onde está o erro. E diga quais são os erros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A sintaxe do [`toupper()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) não é essa então não vai funcionar mesmo. EM programação não se pode jogar qualquer coisa no código e ver se funciona. Tem que ler documentação e ver como tem que usar.

Mesmo que a sintaxe estivesse certa ainda não resolveria porque a documentação diz que ele modifica um caractere e não toda a *string*.

Converter todos caracteres para depois compará-los é ineficiente. Então ou tem que fazer uma função que varre toda a *string* comparando sem considerar a sensibilidade de caixa ou usar uma função pronta. O problema é que não tem uma função pronta padrão para isto. No Windows existe a [`_stricmp()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stricmp-wcsicmp-mbsicmp-stricmp-l-wcsicmp-l-mbsicmp-l). No Linux pode usar [`strcasecmp()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcasecmp.3.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main(void) {
    char lugar[20]; //cria o array de caracteres para armazenar o texto
    printf("Digite o nome de um lugar: ");
    scanf("%20s", lugar); //não precisa da referência porque o array já é uma, precisa %s
    if (strcasecmp(lugar, "Escola") == 0) { //use a função para comparar todos os caracteres
        printf("\nEstudar");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/tPvN6K). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vdpepodj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/CaseInsensitiveComparison.c).

Comment: Obrigado novamente bigown pela paciência por explicar o código, sou novato se comparado a todos aqui do Stackoverflow, programo somente á 2 anos, e eu não estou acostumado a olhar a documentação de C (outras linguagens eu sempre olho), mas vou começar a olhar sim.